# Выпадающий список, который заменяет стиль и ссылку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

В общем, попытался сам создать кнопку, но в JS я не очень разбираюсь.

Идея такова, есть `<button>`, хотелось бы сделать около него стрелку(стрелочку, arrow), при нажатии на неё чтобы появлялся плавно блок и к примеру, при выборе "Скачать с ЯД"- менялась ссылка в  `<button>`, а также стиль(к примеру `background-color`, `color`, и т.п. тоже в `<button>`)
Хочеться чтобы "Скачать с ЯД", "Скчать с Гугл" - были Font Awesome. 
Понимаю что без своих примеров- но у меня просто напросто ничего не получилось, идеи есть, а реализация хромает :(

[image: Вот что должно получиться]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не стал заморачиваться с такой "механикой" и сделал бы выпадающий список с ссылками.

```css
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css);

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}

.button .placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button .placeholder::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button .placeholder .text,
.button .placeholder i {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.button .placeholder .text {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.button .placeholder i {
  width: 20px;
}

.button .links {
  display: none;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  margin: 1px 3px 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button .links a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.button .links a:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.button .links a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.button:hover .links {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="placeholder">
    <div class="text">Скачать</div>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Скачать с Яндекс.Диск</a>
    <a href="#">Скачать с Google Drive</a>
    <a href="#">Скачать с Dropbox</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Но если прям хочется, то вот

```js
// При нажатии на список с ссылками
$('.button .links span').on('click', function() {
  let links = $(this).data('href'), // Получаем ссылку из data-href
    linksName = $(this).text(); // Получаем "название" ссылки
  $(this).closest('.button').find('.text').attr('href', links).text(linksName); // Возвращаемся к самой "ссылке" и добавляем в неё выбранную ссылку, ну и добавляем название, так, чисто для визуализации.
});

// Проверка на "скачать", что ссылки нет (отмена перенаправления)
$('.button .text').on('click', function() {
  let link = $(this).attr('href');
  if (link == '' || link == '#' || link == '/') return false;
});
```

```css
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css);

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}

.button .placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button .placeholder::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button .placeholder .text,
.button .placeholder i {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.button .placeholder .text {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.button .placeholder i {
  width: 20px;
}

.button .links {
  display: none;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  margin: 1px 3px 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button .links span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.button .links span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.button .links span:hover {
  color: red;
}

.button:hover .links {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button">
  <div class="placeholder">
    <a href="#" class="text">Скачать</a>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <span data-href="#">Скачать с Яндекс.Диск</span>
    <span data-href="#">Скачать с Google Drive</span>
    <span data-href="#">Скачать с Dropbox</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сработало, и добавило пару идей, смотри я сделал `<span class="dropdownbutt">
 <i.....> </span>` для кнопки, как реализовать открытие блока именно по нажатию на `span`?
[>>Вот скрин<<](https://i.imgur.com/nsoM75K.png)

Comment: Можете залить на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), например и скинуть сюда?